# how can I make the best model in probit link

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I am new to R and I am trying all possible model combination
 using Generalized Linear Models and logistic regression with a probit link. However, when I run the code, none of the model seems to be adequate
I know  that if one of the model is adequate it is the best model.
This is my code, is there anything wrong with it ?

```
install.packages("glm2")
library(glm2)
data("heart")
attach(heart)
head(heart)
nondeath<-c(Patients - Deaths)
nondeath
logreg4<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup+Severity+Delay+Region,family=binomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg4)
1-pchisq(109.02,69)##model is not adequate 0.001524977
logreg6<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup*Severity+Delay+Region,family=binomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg6)
1-pchisq(88.607,68)#0.04740388
logreg7<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup*Severity*Delay+Region,family=binomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg7)
1-pchisq(85.906,65)#0.04232451
logreg8<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup*Severity*Delay*Region,family=binomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg8)###model is not adequate 0.04740388


logreg5<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup*Severity+Delay+Region,family=quasibinomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg5)
1-pchisq(79.485,58)##model is not adequate 0.04740388
logreg9<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup*Severity*Delay+Region,family=quasibinomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg9)#0.04232451
logreg0<-glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~AgeGroup*Severity*Delay*Region,family=quasibinomial(link = probit))
summary(logreg0)##model is not adequate 0.04740388
```

Comment: What exactly does "adequate " mean to you. This seems more like a question about model fitting than programming. It might be a better fit for [stats.se] than Stack Overflow but it still seems misguided. There's no guarantee there's any sort of relationship between the variables you've collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a dataset in glm2 that is used to demonstrate problems in glm convergence, but you don't use glm2 but glm.
You need to first transform variables into factors, here you have numerics, so use

```
logreg4<-
glm(cbind(Deaths,nondeath)~factor(AgeGroup)+factor(Severity)+factor(Delay)+factor(Region),family=binomial(link 
= probit))
```

When looking at your residuals, there is something wrong, so it would probably be better to use a log link with your dataset. Check ? glm2 for some examples.
You could select the model with the lowest AIC.